# Sitecore Content Search Exception: Entry point was not found

Tags: solr, content-search, configuration, dependency-injection

I'm having an issue taking an older version of our site running under Sitecore 7.2 (with some older dll's such as glass mapper) and switching over from Lucene to Solr (6.6.2).

I've followed the steps for setting up Solr/Sitecore, however the first issue I had was that, I was missing some solr.config files in the `app_config/includes` folder, so I "borrowed" them from a functional Solr 6.6.2/Sitecore 8.2 instance.

I'm hoping that's not problem number one.

When I try to load the 7.2 site (after following the Solr setup steps), I get the following error:

> [EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
>          Sitecore.Abstractions.ISettings.GetSetting(String name, String defaultValue) +0
>
> Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_IsEnabled()
>   +72
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args) +13
>              (Object , Object[] ) +71
>              Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +331
>              Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +208
>              Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +673
>              System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +201
>              System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context,
>
> HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +1069
>     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext
>   context) +382
>
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +433

I originally had put the `IOC.Unity.config` file in the `app_config/includes` folder, thinking that was a needed file, but it produced a similar, yet longer error message, so I have it currently disabled.

I'm wondering if this a pipeline issue. Since I copied some configs from the 8.2 instance, maybe it's possible those configs are incompatible / need to be rewritten to be useful.

I also copied a few dll's from the 8.2 bin folder (`Sitecore.abstractions.dll`, etc), that were not present in the 7.2 install. Hope this isn't what's causing the issue.

In case it might be helpful, below is my `global.asax` file.

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.UnityIntegration.UnityApplication" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Diagnostics" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Glass.Sitecore.Mapper" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes" %>

<script runat="server">
     public void Application_Start() {
        AttributeConfigurationLoader loader = new
        AttributeConfigurationLoader
     (
        new string[] { 
            "MedTouch.Base.BLL"
        }
     );

 Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Context context = new
 Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Context(loader);
 }

 </script>
```

Would appreciate any suggestions to get around this error, it's got me pretty roadblocked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look. You can't actually copy paste random spare bits from various versions of Sitecore and expect to make it work.

While I will not rule out, a certain amount of retrofitting might be made to work - what you're doing here is too far removed.

1. Sitecore 8.2 uses a completely different IoC system; the built in DI container by Sitecore. Unity is no longer a requirement for SOLR setup
2. Sitecore 8.2 is on a completely different .NET version than 7.2
3. Solr 6.6.2 is not officially supported on any Sitecore version. But 6.6.1 is supported on Sitecore 9. Not even 8.

Put your DLLs back to how they were. If you want to use SOLR 6.6.2 with your Sitecore version, go grab the SOLRNET APIs and hand implement.

- https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet

Comment: Well as there's no *official* guide to setting this up in sitecore 7 (most of the solr setup guides I have found relate to version 8), I have been winging it, so much of what I've been attempting is trial and error (probably more on the error side).

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore 7.2 does not support Solr 6.6.2. At the moment I'm writing this answer, even Sitecore 9.0.1 officially doesn't support Solr 6.6.2.

For the supported Solr versions, check [Solr compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897).

My advice:

1. Remove all the dlls and configs from Sitecore 8.2 which you've copied to Sitecore 7.2 (and NEVER EVEN do that again).
2. Install Solr version supported by Sitecore 7.2
3. Check the comments below the table in the link above - there are some modifications required for the newer Solr versions if you want to use them with Sitecore 7.2

Comment: Perhaps not officially, however in my experiments, I have sitecore 8.2 / solr 6.6.2 running on my local machine just fine together. So in that table, I'm choosing to interpret the bit about 6.6.1 having no compatibility information as they just haven't gotten around to trying it out yet. 

6.6.2 / 8.2 a best practice? Maybe not, but it *can* be done.